# Android load url in internal WebView issue

Tags: android-webview

I have a problem with a specific site when loading in my apps internal webview.

In the LogCat i get these 2 lines (the tag is "chromium").

```
[INFO:CONSOLE(25)] "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'getItem' of null", source: http://m.ynet.co.il/Default_Ynet.aspx?type=3&id=4519238 (25)
[INFO:CONSOLE(73)] "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'push' of undefined", source: http://m.ynet.co.il/Default_Ynet.aspx?type=3&id=4519238 (73)
```

If i redirect to the external browser all is fine. Also it happens only with the above site (see in logcat)

```
public class WebActivity extends Activity {
WebView wv;
final Activity activity = this;
@SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
    this.getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_PROGRESS);
    setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(true);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_web);
    wv = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView1);
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    final String url = intent.getStringExtra("url");
    Log.i("webView", url);
    wv.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    wv.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    wv.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);  
    wv.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);  
    wv.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
        public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress)
        {
            activity.setTitle("Loading...");
            activity.setProgress(progress * 100);

            if(progress == 100)
                activity.setTitle(R.string.app_name);
        }
    });
    wv.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url)
        {
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }
    });

    wv.loadUrl(url);
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: probably unrelated but don't call loadUrl from shouldOverrideUrlLoading, return false instead.

Comment: @marcin.kosiba If you could please explain why that would be great for learning :-)

Comment: `shouldOverrideUrlLoading` is called for subframes with non-https schemes. If you go to a a page like http://jsbin.com/gupug/1/quiet your code will end up calling view.loadUrl('tel:1234') and you will end up showing an error page, since the webview doesn't know how to load a tel: URL.

Comment: @marcin.kosiba thanks for the explanation. How about my problem?

Comment: no idea. the errors in logcat look like JavaScript errors. Connect DevTools and check which fields are undefined.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that there was a problem using the shouldOverrideUrlLoading method (below) with this particular site.

```
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url)
    {
        view.loadUrl(url);
        return true;
    }
```

Once this was deleted all was good...